# Congruence not a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How to show that $5i+3\mod 12i+7$ is not an integer square, for any integer $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ ? I do not see where to start. Thanks in advance.
>
> @ Ragnar Thanks. I would like to show that $M\neq N^{2}$
>    with $M\equiv\left(5*i+3\right)\left(mod\left(12*i+7\right)\right)$ is true at least for $i\geq0$ ($M,N\in\mathbb{\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}}$) and my idea was to show it by induction. It is obviously true for $i=0$. Then if it is true for $i$, it should also be true for $i+1$. But this is where I do not know how to proceed. $M\equiv\left(5*i+3\right)\left(mod\left(12*i+7\right)\right)$  means that $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $M=k\left(12*i+7\right)+\left(5*i+3\right)$. Posing $k=x+y$ and $i=y$ ($x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$) yields $M=3\left(2y+1\right)^{2}+x\left(12y+7\right)$ or $M=4\left(3y\left(x+y+1\right)+x\right)+3\left(x+1\right)$. But I cannot obtain a full square expression. Is that a right way to go ? Or is there a simpler way ?
>
> @ Pete L. Clark Thanks also. Well, I know a little bit about modular arithmetic.
>
> @ Abishanka and @ Bill Thanks also. $\left(mod\,5\right)$ squares are $0$ or $1$ or $4\left(mod\,5\right)$. So a $3\left(mod\,5\right)$ is obviously not a square but how does it apply to the expression of $M$ above ?
>
> > I have found the following : For $i,j>0, \iota\geq0\in\mathbb{Z}$, one has to show that an integer square can never be $\left(5i+3\right)\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)$. As $12i+7\equiv1\left(mod\,2\right)$, the series of values of $j^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)$ for $0\leq j\leq12i+6$ is obviously symmetric, i.e. $j^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)\equiv\left(12i+7-j\right)^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)$. So it is sufficient to consider $0\leq j\leq6i+3$ only. Then for $0\leq j\leq\left\lfloor \sqrt{12i+7}\right\rfloor$ (where $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$), $j^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)$ are all squared integers $<\left(12i+7\right)$ and clearly squared integers cannot be of the form $\left(5i+3\right)$, i.e. $3\left(mod\,5\right)$. For $\left\lfloor \sqrt{12i+7}\right\rfloor <j\leq6i+3$, let $j=6i+3-\iota$, with $0\leq\iota<\left(6i+3-\left\lfloor \sqrt{12i+7}\right\rfloor \right)$; then $j^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)=\left(6i+3-\iota\right)^{2}\left(mod\,\left(12i+7\right)\right)$, i.e. $\exists k=\left(3i-\iota+1\right)>0,\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\left(6i+3-\iota\right)^{2}-k\left(12i+7\right)=3i+2+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)$ as long as $3i+2+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)<12i+7$. If $3i+2+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)>12i+7$, then $k=\left(3i-\iota+2\right)$ is taken yielding $\left(6i+3-\iota\right)^{2}-k\left(12i+7\right)=-9i-5+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)$. And so on. In all cases, $\left(6i+3-\iota\right)^{2}-k\left(12i+7\right)=3i+2+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)$ or $-9i-5+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)$ or any $3i+2+\iota\left(\iota+1\right)-k\left(12i+7\right)$ is always different from $\left(5i+3\right)$. Therefore, $m\neq k\left(12i+7\right)+\left(5i+3\right)$.
> >     Is this correct ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve this problem? Do you have any ideas? Also, for positive $i$, $12i+7>5i+3$, so in that case, the modulo is not nessecary.

Comment: Hint: do you know anything about modular arithmetic?

Comment: My suggestion would be to begin by splitting the proof in half with  preliminary substitutions, the first $i=n$, the second $i=-n$, and $n \in \mathbb N$, this will allow you to work with remainders of the same sign convention, which will then make it much more straight forward to then combine your proofs for the two separate cases and make a declaration on $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ n > 5i\!+\!3\ \Rightarrow\ 5i\!+\!3\,\ {\rm mod\,\ } n\ =\ 5i\!+\!3\ \equiv 3\pmod 5.\,$ But, mod $5,\,$ squares are $\,\equiv \,\ldots$

Comment: It says $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $5i+3>12i+7$ for $i\leq-1$. So this answer doesn't suffice.

Comment: @Abishanka The OP doesn't say how his mod operation works with negative moduli. If it returns a negative remainder then that is obviously not a square. If it returns the least positive rep then the same idea as above works, reducing not mod $5$, but another modulus.